# array inside method ruby with each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, foreach

I have this method

```
def last_board

 user = current_user #current_user

 boards = current_user.boards #return every boards that belongs to current_user e.g. [#<Board _id: 4f2968ac1d41c81c7c000063, _type: "Board", created_at...] 

 followers = user.all_followers #return every followers of user [#<User _id: 4f2862b21d41c847e200005b, _type: "User" reset_password_sent_at: nil, confirmation_token: nil,...]

 followers.each do |follower|
  boards.each do |board| 
  # I want to be a follower of user, if I am following at least one board of this user  
  #I want run this code, "follower.unfollow(user)", only if follower does not following any user's board.
 #this method "follower.follower_of?(board)" return true or false if follower follow board
  end       
 end
```

Comment: @three Thank you I don't know how use any. Can you paste a example? Thank you

Comment: sure, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F you can also use other Enumerable methods that might fit better for your use case. It depends on your use case which I did not fully understand :) But from what I think you mean is that you want to discard objects if something is false (none?). Or you want to keep if true (any?).

Comment: @three I want run the code `follower.unfollow(user)` only if follower does not following none user's board. The board belongs to user. If the follower not follow none board that belongs_to user, then run the code `follower.unfollow(user)` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can something like this

```
followers.each do |follower|
     is_having_any_board = false
     follower.boards.each do |follower_board|
         boards.each do |board| 
            if(follower_board.id == board.id)#delete last )
               is_having_any_board = true
               break;
            end
         end
     end

     if(is_having_any_board)
         follower.follow(user)
     else
         follower.unfollow(user)
     end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I get undefined method `is_having_board' for #<User:0xc1532e8>

Comment: i considered that you will write that method to check if a follower is having that a particular board. btw i have updated the answer, try this i hope this will work this time.

Comment: Thank you. No error now, but run **follower.unfollow(user) for every user's follower**. This is bad, because when user delete this board, if a follower follow other board from user, The follower leave to follow to user. The kit from this question is, **I want to be a follower of user, if I am following at least one board of this user** or the other side, I want delete my relation with the user with `follower.unfollow(user)` if I dont follow none or 0 board of this user.

Comment: thats good.. i understand what you said , i guess you should be able to do be seeing the above answer, i cant say anything because i dont know the implementation inside follow and unfollow method.

Comment: Thank you @dku.rajkumar I use this gem https://github.com/lastomato/mongoid_followable the methods follow and unfollow you can see https://github.com/lastomato/mongo_followable/blob/master/lib/mongo_followable/follower.rb#L127